# 403 access denied on site variation root

Tags: 2013, site-collection, publishing-site, access-denied, variations

I moved a site from one server to another. Site is using variations.

On new server if I open page directly for e.g. `http://myserver/en/Pages/default.aspx` then it opens the page but if I just go to `http://myserver` OR `http://myserver/Pages/VariationRoot.aspx` then I get 403 access denied error.

I am both a farm admin and site collection administrator of this site. It's working fine on previous server. What could be the reason of this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I fixed it by enabling Anonymous access on web application and then disabling it again.